# Bootstrap-Timepicker only

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, datepicker, timepicker

I want to make a textbox withg time picker only
How to make that from this    http://jsfiddle.net/RR4hw/11/

```
jQuery("#startDate").on("dp.change",function (e) {
jQuery('#endDate').data("DateTimePicker").setMinDate(e.date);
});
jQuery("#endDate").on("dp.change",function (e) {
jQuery('#startDate').data("DateTimePicker").setMaxDate(e.date);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".timeField").datetimepicker({
pickDate: false
});
```